# elixir dynamic module call

Tags: dynamic, module, elixir

How can I call function func() in a module called App.Reporting.Name

based on the string "name" which is not known until runtime

using String.to_atom or to_existing_atom does not work :

```
 alias App.Reporting.Name
 module = "name" |> String.capitalise |> String.to_atom     
 apply(module, :func, [])
```

Without the alias, this does not work either

```
module = "App.Reporting.Name" |> String.to_atom     
apply(module, :func, [])
```

I get an (UndefinedFunctionError) and (module :"App.Reporting.Name" is not available)

thanks

Answer (score 9):

Your second approach is almost correct, you just need to prefix `Elixir.` because `App.Reporting.Name` is equal to `:"Elixir.App.Reporting.Name"`, not `:"App.Reporting.Name"` since Elixir prefixes all module names (names starting with an uppercase letter) with `Elixir.` before turning it into an atom:

```
iex(1)> App.Reporting.Name == :"App.Reporting.Name"
false
iex(2)> App.Reporting.Name == :"Elixir.App.Reporting.Name"
true
```

So, this code should work:

```
module = "Elixir.App.Reporting.Name" |> String.to_atom     
apply(module, :func, [])
```

and so should this:

```
module = Module.concat(App.Reporting, "name" |> String.capitalize |> String.to_atom)
apply(module, :func, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason yours isn't working is because the `String.to_atom` does just that, turns a string into an atom. Because there is no module called "App.Reporting.Name" it's most likely `App.Reporting.Name` it errors.

Not sure if this is the *best* way to do this, just one that sprang to mind. But you could do something like this:

```
iex(2)> module = "Casing"
"Casing"
iex(3)> Module.concat(String, "#{module}") |> apply(:upcase, ["test sentence"])
"TEST SENTENCE"
```

Another solution could be to create a macro that automatically does this process, however that is not something I am that great at so you will have to go through the docs [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html) for that one.